# When i import collections in my Python file, I can't access Ordered Dictionary?

Tags: python, collections, ordereddictionary

[missing ordered dictionary in collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x7NC.jpg)

It is all said, I cant acces ordered dictionary. I have searched everywhere but there is no solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for `collections.OrderedDict`, not `collections.ordereddict`.

Case matters, as your IDE appears to be case-sensitive.